# How can I create a recurring task in check lists?

Tags: trello

I am new to Trello and would have several tasks that I need to do regularly. Is there a way in the due date or check list to do this?

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't exist yet. It seems like it might be a good candidate for a plugin.
It has things in common with [Templates](https://trello.com/card/board/templates-for-boards-lists-cards-and-checklists/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e6fdc349d5bce0000004fa6) and [Due Dates v3](https://trello.com/card/board/due-dates-v3-notifications/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e947f12fc0b63a2d63882cd), but the idea of having cards or checklists appear in a recurring fashion has not really been proposed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and have a work around using Google Calendar and the cloud service Zapier.

I set up all the recurring tasks in google calendar, with the start date when I wanted the card to come into my inbox.

Feel free to use one I created earlier. With Zapier you can create a free account which would suffice.

http://zpr.io/Th5

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation with the above mentioned service, otherwise your answer will be considered spam and treated accordingly. Thanks!